# Azure Publish Error only in my controller but not in the homecontroller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

Getting following error,

> An error occurred while processing your request. Request ID:
>   0HLIETLEOHKHF:00000003

Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.

**I have code something asp.net core mvc crud actions and it runs with iss properly but when i publish it with azure; the homecontroller(default visual studio thing) is ok. But my newly controller errors like that.**

Comment: Did you try *setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application* to find out more about the error?

Comment: Yes İ have done someting for it but there is no environment variable inmy project. Someone told this in other similar questions. i exemine it but i cant find ...ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable... i am working with asp.net2.1 someone told about it have changed some like that.

Comment: Nope, `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` still works as it did. If it's not set, it defaults to `Production`, so you can just add it to your environment variables with a value of `Development`. Better still, if you have logs, take a look at those.

Comment: How can i find that environment thing?

Comment: i had done something like that for java before... the environment variables from the computer properties advanced... is this about it? right?

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment variable in App service configuration, then application settings.

Add the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable and set value and restart the app service.